# Add captcha to webform

Tags: 8, webforms, captcha

I'm working on a drupal 8 project, I've created a webform and trying to associate a captcha to my webform using captcha contrib module.
I've a personalized template for my webform in which I render the webform fields.
I've associate the captcha to the webform under /admin/config/people/captcha/captcha-points and test as anonymous user it is always unable to associate captcha to the webform.

- Should I print captcha in my webform template file? if so how to do it?
- Should I add an element Captcha to my webform fields? if so is that element by default use captcha contrib module settings?

Any help is appreciate.

Comment: Install captcha module and create captcha type field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To captcha protect a webform you NEED to add a captcha element to it. When captcha contrib module is enabled on your site the available captcha `challenge types` are available to be used on a per webform basis.

The template twig file is mostly for design puproses.

If the placement of captcha within the form is not to your liking you should copy the default webform template from `/modules/contrib/webform/webform.html.twig` to your theme `/themes/custom/MYTHEME/templates/webform--WEBFORM_MACHINE_NAME.html.twig` and perhaps place each element seperately.

The default `webform.html.twig` is

```
<form{{ attributes }}>
  {{ title_prefix }}
  {{ children }}
  {{ title_suffix }}
</form>
```

And in our own copy we should take out `{{ children }}` and replace with individual elements but also we have to make sure form ids and actions are included manually and it the final template should end up looking similar to this

```
<form{{ attributes }}>
  {{ title_prefix }}
  {{ element.elements.first_name }}
  {{ element.elements.last_name }}
  {{ element.elements.captcha }}

  {# necessary elements #}
  {{ element.form_build_id }}
  {{ element.form_id }}
  {{ element.actions }}

  {{ title_suffix }}
</form>
```

Where `captcha` for example is the machine name of the captcha field

Comment: yeah I've tried this solution and the captcha is rendered but I'm not sure if this added captcha field use exactly the captcha contrib module settings (web site key, private key..) ?

Comment: not sure what the question is.

Comment: does webform use the contrib module Captcha settings for the new created captcha element?

Comment: You should have captcha module installed to add captcha field to webform, so the captcha field will not be available for webform otherwise. What settings do you mean in particular ?

Comment: ok  I've implemented your solution but no validation on captcha answer has been detected. ex: the form is submitted  even with giving wrong answer to the captcha.

Comment: first try without custom webform please and report your findings ... but perhaps try a simpler captcha validation like MATH ?

Comment: yes it works perfectly wthout custom webform template, and when using custom template element.actions doesn't render the submit button but when using element.elements.actions the submit button appears but submitting the form data doesn't work.. any additional point?

Comment: What happens when clicking the SUBMIT button ? Inspect the browser console for any javascript errors

Comment: just reloading the page no js error appeared.

Comment: Please try doing this at a clean drupal installation, perhaps there is a module that messes with your buttons, how about changing the theme (maybe there is something about the theme)

Comment: can you check this http://www.developersdocs.com/blog/drupal-8-theming-define-custom-template-file-form?i=1 is this the right way to override webform template?

Comment: [Override webform template](http://www.developersdocs.com/blog/drupal-8-theming-define-custom-template-file-form?i=1) this solution works for me and the captcha work as you suggest thanks!